# Is there any way to capture AWS Contact attributes when saving a contact for the first time (save button event)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, contact-center

I'm trying to capture the values inserted in the fields of the Contact attribute panel (AWS Connect) whenever you want to create a new customer for your call centre in order to save them in a Dynamo and use them with other implementations by lambda usage (trying to avoid creating a new front as AWS should have a utility like this?)

Please forgive any post formatting errors as its my first ever post here.

Thanks everyone.

I've tried several approaches:

1. Trying to record network traffic to see what the payload delivers (POST) whenever you press the "Save" button -- To no avail, I can see the payload but not its JSON structure more than a few params.
2. Trying to understand where those values are stored within AWS -- To no avail, they are JSON System parametres ($.*parameter*) and I can't seem to be able to access them other than the console, which isn't what I'm looking for.
3. Try searching on Connect API (https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-streams/blob/master/Documentation.md) and try searching for a method that *kind-of* (which isn't the best approach) does what I'm looking for -- None found (at least by lil' inexperienced me).
4. AWS CLI. I saw a few methods portraying (again) *kind of* what I'm looking for. The catch? It's CLI v2.

Answer (score 0):

Any inserts or modifications you make to items in DynamoDB will trigger a stream event in DynamoDB Streams.

You can attach your stream to a Lambda function and listen to all of the item changes, you can filter the steam only to invoke on certain values present in the payload etc..

As you want the values in Lambda I think it's the perfect fit for your use-case.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I don't know if I understand what you're proposing. The thing is I don't have yet those elements in neither lambda or Dynamo, I need to get them from any event that generates when you create a contact in the contact attribute panel, then your solution would be best indeed.